# Lookup minimum and maximum value based on one value in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

Which formula to use in B2 Sheet 1 to get minimum value / oldest date and C2 to get maximum value / newest date

Taking into consideration that ID rows can't be determined hence they might be 3, 4, or more than that

```html
<p>Which formula to use in B2 Sheet 1 to get minimum value / oldest date and C2 to get maximum value / newest date</p>
<p>Taking into consideration that ID rows can't be determined hence they might be 3, 4, or more than that</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Sheet 1</p>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; height: 54px;" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 18px;">
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">ID</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">Date Started</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">Date Finish</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 18px;">
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">45</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">21/11/2021</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">23/11/2021</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 18px;">
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">46</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">21/11/2021</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 18px;">26/11/2021</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>Sheet 2</p>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; height: 168px;" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 18px;">
<td style="width: 16.6667%; height: 18px;">ID</td>
<td style="width: 16.6667%; height: 18px;">unit number</td>
<td style="width: 16.6667%; height: 18px;">material</td>
<td style="width: 16.6667%; height: 18px;">name</td>
<td style="width: 8.33335%;">Date</td>
<td style="width: 14.3783%; height: 18px;">time</td>
<td style="width: 10.6218%; height: 18px;">quantity</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 18px;">
<td style="width: 16.6667%; height: 18px;">
<p><span style="background-color: #ffff00;">45</span></p>
</td>
<td style="width: 16.6667%; height: 18px;">1124</td>
<td style="width: 16.6667%; height: 18px;">45648</td>
<td style="width: 16.6667%; height: 18px;">Apple</td>
<td style="width: 8.33335%;"><span style="background-color: #ffff00;">21/11/2021</span></td>
<td style="width: 14.3783%; height: 18px;">12:00 AM</td>
<td style="width: 10.6218%; height: 18px;">70</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 42px;">
<td style="width: 16.6667%; height: 42px;"><span style="background-color: #ffff00;">45</span></td>
<td style="width: 16.6667%; height: 42px;">
<p>1124</p>
</td>
<td style="width: 16.6667%; height: 42px;">45648</td>
<td style="width: 16.6667%; height: 42px;">Apple</td>
<td style="width: 8.33335%;"><span style="background-color: #ffff00;">22/11/2021</span></td>
<td style="width: 14.3783%; height: 42px;">1:00 AM</td>
<td style="width: 10.6218%; height: 42px;">70</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 18px;">
<td style="width: 16.6667%; height: 18px;"><span style="background-color: #ffff00;">45</span></td>
<td style="width: 16.6667%; height: 18px;">1124</td>
<td style="width: 16.6667%; height: 18px;">45648</td>
<td style="width: 16.6667%; height: 18px;">Apple</td>
<td style="width: 8.33335%;"><span style="background-color: #ffff00;">23/11/2021</span></td>
<td style="width: 14.3783%; height: 18px;">2:00 AM</td>
<td style="width: 10.6218%; height: 18px;">70</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 18px;">
<td style="width: 16.6667%; height: 18px;"><span style="background-color: #00ffff;">46</span></td>
<td style="width: 16.6667%; height: 18px;">1521</td>
<td style="width: 16.6667%; height: 18px;">46565</td>
<td style="width: 16.6667%; height: 18px;">Banana</td>
<td style="width: 8.33335%;"><span style="background-color: #00ffff;">21/11/2021</span></td>
<td style="width: 14.3783%; height: 18px;">5:00 PM</td>
<td style="width: 10.6218%; height: 18px;">70</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 18px;">
<td style="width: 16.6667%; height: 18px;"><span style="background-color: #00ffff;">46</span></td>
<td style="width: 16.6667%; height: 18px;">1521</td>
<td style="width: 16.6667%; height: 18px;">46565</td>
<td style="width: 16.6667%; height: 18px;">Banana</td>
<td style="width: 8.33335%;"><span style="background-color: #00ffff;">21/11/2021</span></td>
<td style="width: 14.3783%; height: 18px;">5:30 PM</td>
<td style="width: 10.6218%; height: 18px;">70</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 18px;">
<td style="width: 16.6667%; height: 18px;"><span style="background-color: #00ffff;">46</span></td>
<td style="width: 16.6667%; height: 18px;">1521</td>
<td style="width: 16.6667%; height: 18px;">46565</td>
<td style="width: 16.6667%; height: 18px;">Banana</td>
<td style="width: 8.33335%;"><span style="background-color: #00ffff;">22/11/2021</span></td>
<td style="width: 14.3783%; height: 18px;">8:00 PM</td>
<td style="width: 10.6218%; height: 18px;">70</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 18px;">
<td style="width: 16.6667%; height: 18px;"><span style="background-color: #00ffff;">46</span></td>
<td style="width: 16.6667%; height: 18px;">1521</td>
<td style="width: 16.6667%; height: 18px;">46565</td>
<td style="width: 16.6667%; height: 18px;">Banana</td>
<td style="width: 8.33335%;"><span style="background-color: #00ffff;">26/11/2021</span></td>
<td style="width: 14.3783%; height: 18px;">11:00 PM</td>
<td style="width: 10.6218%; height: 18px;">70</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Which formula to use in B2 Sheet 1 to get minimum value / oldest date and C2 to get maximum value / newest date

Taking into consideration that ID rows can't be determined hence they might be 3, 4, or more than that

Comment: Erm... did you look at this post before (or even after) committing? I think you were trying to add a table, but instead pasted some html as "code". Please edit.

Comment: If you run the snippet, it gets much clearer. Which version of excel are you on?

Answer (score 0):

These formulas will only work for o365. Just tell, if you need formulas for earlier versions.

For a unique list of `ID`s in column `A` you can use

```
=UNIQUE(A5:A10)
```

In column `B` you can use this

```
=MINIFS($E$5:$E$10,$A$5:$A$10,A1)
```

for the oldest date. And if you switch the `MINIFS` to `MAXIFS`, you get the newest date in column `C`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per my below screenshot, use below formulas.

<kbd>A2</kbd> cell formula `=IFERROR(INDEX($F$5:$F$11,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,$F$5:$F$11),0,0),0)),"")`
<kbd>B2</kbd> cell formula `=MIN(IF($F$5:$F$11=A2,$J$5:$J$11,""))`
<kbd>C2</kbd> cell formula `=MAX(IF($F$5:$F$11=A2,$J$5:$J$11,""))`

Confirm with array entry (`CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`) for B2 and C2 cell formulas.

If you are on ***Microsoft-365*** then can be simplified like below.

```
A2=UNIQUE(F5:F11)
B2=MINIFS(J5:J11,F5:F11,A2#)
C2=MAXIFS(J5:J11,F5:F11,A2#)
```

[image]

Comment: didn't work, I tried both the online version and array formula. what is needed is that when you enter the unique id in cell A2 manually say 45, then you enter all data related to that id 45 in the second table, you don't know how long the table will be as you may enter 10 rows for ID45 but 7 for ID46. so it is like vlookup workflow getting minimum and maximum Also you should not presume the size of the table for id 45 or 46, these need to be recognised based on how manny rows has been added using each ID.